# Solr Delta Import

Tags: solr, delta-index

We have a Post Table

```
       Post
        PostID, Title, Description, isDeleted, ModifiedDateTime
```

and Each Post can be assigned  or deleted multiple Tags

```
         Tag
           TagID, PostID, TagValue
```

How can i Write a sub entity Tag, when i do a delta import if a Tag is Deleted or a New Tag is added then
   Post Document should be Updated  ?

Here is a part of  my mapping.xml

```
      <document name="CollabDocument">

      <entity name="post" transformer="RegexTransformer" dataSource="db" pk="PostID" 

      query="SELECT PostID, Title, Description, CreatedDate FROM Post where isDeleted =   
       0"

     deltaImportQuery="select PostID, Title, Description,CreatedDate FROM Post where              
     PostID='${dataimporter.delta.PostID}'"

     deltaQuery="select PostID from Post where ModifiedDate >

       ${dataimporter.last_index_time}' and isDeleted = 0"

            deletedPkQuery="select PostID from Post where isDeleted = 1">       

    <field column="PostID" name="id" />

     <field column="PostID" name="PostID" />

    <field column="Title" name="Title" />

     <field column="Description" name="Description" />

     <field column="CreatedDate"  name="CreatedDate"/>      

              <entity name="Triples"  dataSource="db" transformer="RegexTransformer"

               query="select group_concat(ts.value separator '|') AS TagValues from 
               tags ts  where ts.postid = ${post.PostID} group by ts.PostId">

          <field name="TagValues" column="TagValues" /> 

             </entity>
```

Comment: what do you mean with a sub-entity? Do you want put both entities (Post and Tag) on the same document? Can you show me how your schema.xml will be?

Comment: Do you change the _ModifiedDateTime_ of a Post when a tag is added/removed?

Comment: @Alexander sorry i meant Tag as Nested Entity of Post.

Comment: @cheffe Yes i can update the ModifiedDateTime of Post if a Tag is Deleted or a New  Tag is added.